# How do you put a jquery function inside a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am validating my form using Javascript, but would like to display the errors using Jquery. Can you do this?

Comment: Nope this is impossible. jQuery is magic, and it does'nt work with javascript at all.

Comment: post your code about what you are looking for. By the way did you include jquery library?

Comment: @adeneo, definitely its possible to use jquery inside javascript.

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library, so javascript will obviously work with it.

Comment: @Pramod He was being sarcastic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this:

```
function Validate(){
    if(isValidate){
       // do somthing
    }else{
       $("#error").fadeIn(500);// here is jQuery code
    }
}
```